# .iml': ParseError when project opens in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I tried to open flutter project but unable to open flutter file but project exists to their location. I also tried to delete .iml file but nothing is happening and all software is already updated

> Load Settings         Cannot load settings from file
>   'E:\Farhana_Sample\ABC\lotus.iml': ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[1,1]       Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.      Please
>   correct the file content

[image]

`.yaml` and other file also showing error that

> **file was loaded in wrong encoded:UTF 8**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open you iml file with notpad and copy content and paste in file android studio it will work